# Matlab: ezplot two functions in one graph

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I did a Newton interpolation and defined it via `cotNewton = @(x)[...]`, where `[...]` is some function and is too large to post. I would like to compare it with `cot(x)`, so I did

```
syms x;
figure; 
hold on; 
ezplot(cot(x)); 
ezplot(cotNewton);
```

However, the graph I get only shows `cotNewton`. What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you call `ezplot` *after the first time*, to place more than one trace on the same figure, you will need to manually set it on the figure.  Unfortunately `ezplot` doesn't work the same way as how `plot` works when it comes to `hold on`.  As such, do something like:

```
syms x
ezplot(cot(x));
hold on;
p1 = ezplot(cotNewton); %// Grab a handle to the next ezplot graph
%// Set it on the figure
set(p1,'Color','red', 'LineStyle', '--', 'LineWidth', 2);
title('My Graph');
hold off;
```